# How to change CupertinoSwitch size in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the size of the CupertinoSwitch in flutter. I have tried putting the switch in Container but changing the size of the container does not affect the switch.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Transform.scale` and set `scale`, 1 means normal size, 0.8 means smaller size

code snippet

```
Transform.scale(
                        scale: 0.8,
                        child: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: _switchValue,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _switchValue = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CupertinoSwitchDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {    
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoSwitchDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/cupertino/switch';

  @override
  _CupertinoSwitchDemoState createState() => _CupertinoSwitchDemoState();
}

class _CupertinoSwitchDemoState extends State<CupertinoSwitchDemo> {

  bool _switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: const Text('Switch'),
        // We're specifying a back label here because the previous page is a
        // Material page. CupertinoPageRoutes could auto-populate these back
        // labels.
        previousPageTitle: 'Cupertino',
        //trailing: CupertinoDemoDocumentationButton(CupertinoSwitchDemo.routeName),
      ),
      child: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.textStyle,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Semantics(
                  container: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Transform.scale(
                        scale: 0.8,
                        child: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: _switchValue,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _switchValue = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                          "Enabled - ${_switchValue ? "On" : "Off"}"
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Semantics(
                  container: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: true,
                        onChanged: null,
                      ),
                      Text(
                          'Disabled - On'
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Semantics(
                  container: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: false,
                        onChanged: null,
                      ),
                      Text(
                          'Disabled - Off'
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help you. thanks.

Comment: It works, thank you! Is it only my feeling that google neglect Cupertino wigets in flutter. Isn't here better way?

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer solves almost everything you need. But keep in mind that, if you make your widget smaller with `Transform.scale` you still have the same invisible space that the widget had before scaling it. That means: even if you scale your `Switch`, it still occupies the original size. A workaround for that is just to wrap it with a container and give it a desired width and height.

Note: After scaling your `Switch`, in order **to not** apply the transformation when performing hit tests, set `transformHitTests` to `false`. That way you can more easily control the area where you can tap or click.

```
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 30, //set desired REAL HEIGHT
                        width: 35, //set desired REAL WIDTH
                        child: Transform.scale(
                          transformHitTests: false,
                          scale: .5,
                          child: CupertinoSwitch(
                            value: switchValue,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                switchValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 10):

using ***Transform.scale*** is really a good way of doing it but can cause you some trouble designing or arranging widgets on the screen.
So instead, you can wrap your ***CupertinoSwitch*** in ***FittedBox*** which is inside another ***Container***, giving you more control over your widget.

You can copy-paste the below code,
you only need to set height and width and make your ***FittedBox*** to ***BoxFit.contain***.

```
        Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      width: 200.0,
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: CupertinoSwitch(
                          value: _switchValue,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                             setState(() {
                          _switchValue = value;
                        });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```